# App crashing when using Flutter firebase_core - reason: 'App name can only contain alphanumeric, hyphen (-), and underscore (_) characters'

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

When adding support for Firebase to my Flutter app, on iOS I get the following exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: 'App name can only contain alphanumeric, hyphen (-), and underscore (_) characters'
```

Looking at flutterfire [issue #928](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/928) I was wondering if this had to do with the iOS bundle ID. So I changed this to comply to the above (using hypens instead of dots). But this did not solve the issue.

I also tried to adjust the iOS "Bundle display name". But this didn't help either.

So - my question is; what is the "App name"? And how can I change it?

Answer (score 8):

App Name refers to the Firebase App Name given when initializing Firebase in the main.dart. Make sure that name doesn't have white spaces (' ') or other unauthorized characters.

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: 'app-name',
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Does [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13518#issuecomment-351910058) help?

It suggests a quick fix which is to replace "_" by "-".

Go to your info.plist file and you will see:

```
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>App Name</string>
```

You can then make your change.

Comment: Thx - and Yes - but where? What is the "App name" which is referred to in the error message?

Comment: Updated my answer.